# Is there anyway to get more control over when CRON runs?

Tags: cron, rules

I've just setup some rules using the Rules Scheduler module. Everything is working as expected, except that when a rule is scheduled for 10:30am, it might not run til 11:00am, because that is when CRON runs.

Furthermore, when I go to the CRON settings page, it only allows me to select the intervals which CRON runs at.

Is there anyway to schedule a CRON task, e.g. everyday at 10:30? If is there anyway to be sure that if I set CRON to run at 1 hour intervals, CRON is running on the hour, and not some random time, based off when someone last pressed the run cron button?

I'm running Drupal 7 on a Windows platform is that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using 'lazy' cron this means the cron process only kicks off if 
your cron requirements are met and someone visits the page

i.e. cron is set to run every two hours, 
cron hasn't been run for two hours 
and someone is on your site. (this could be 2 hours after the last cron run or 2 weeks)

It is only triggered by people visiting the site.

You need to setup a script to visit the site every say half hour. 
see this guide http://drupal.org/node/31506

Note: windows task scheduler is windows version of cron.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "Elysia Cron" or "Cron Control" module to control the cron.

I have not worked on "cron control" module, but I have used "Elysia Cron" module to manage different cron in the site.

Elysia Cron: http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron
Cron Control: http://drupal.org/project/cron_control